# Как перевести вектор в углы эйлера? c++

Tags: c++, vector, вектор

Пытаюсь восстановить код функции:

```
QAngles = vecDir.ToEulerAngles ( &vecUp );
```

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/QAngle
`vecDir` и `vecUp`  векторы.

`vecUp`  может быть `0`

```
QAngles = vecDir.ToEulerAngles ( );
```

Можете что подсказать?

В интернете нашел, но не знаю откуда взять `w` или `r`.

```
void Quaternion::ToEulerAngles(Vector3D & v) const
{
    float sqw = w * w;
    float sqx = x * x;
    float sqy = y * y;
    float sqz = z * z;
    float unit = sqx + sqy + sqz + sqw; // if normalised is one, otherwise is correction factor
    float test = x * y + z * w;
    if (test > 0.499f * unit) // singularity at north pole
    {
        v.y = 2.0f * atan2f(x, w);
        v.z = FLOAT_PI / 2.0f;
        v.x = 0.0f;
        return;
    }
    if (test < -0.499f * unit) // singularity at south pole
    {
        v.y = -2.0f * atan2f(x, w);
        v.z = -FLOAT_PI / 2.0f;
        v.x = 0;
        return;
    }
    v.y = atan2f(2.0f * y * w - 2.0f * x * z, sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw);
    v.z = asinf(2.0f * test / unit);
    v.x = atan2f(2.0f * x * w - 2.0f * y * z, -sqx + sqy - sqz + sqw);
    return;
}

Vector3 
Quaternion::toEulerAngles() const
{
   float sqw = r * r;    
   float sqx = x * x;    
   float sqy = y * y;    
   float sqz = z * z;    

   Vector3 euler(
      atan2( 2.0f * (x * y + z * r), sqx - sqy - sqz + sqw),            
      asin( -2.0f * (x * z - y * r)),
      atan2( 2.0f * (y * z + x * r), -sqx - sqy + sqz + sqw));
   return euler;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно из контекста, что эта функция вообще должна делать, если только исходить из вашей формулировки. Вырванная из контекста строчка не имеет вообще никакого смысла без описания что представляют эти векторы и как должен быть результат.

QAngle  - это никакой не вектор, это ротейшен, три его элемента есть ни что иное как углы поворота вокруг осей ССК (связанной системы координат).

- X тангаж(pitch)  +вверх/-вниз
- Y рыскание(yaw)  +left/-right
- Z крен(roll)  +right/-left

То что вы нашли, это для кватернионов, и не самый оптимальный вариант. Кватернион это представление вращения в виде 4-х мерного комплексного числа, там другой формат, w - то компонент кватерниона.

Многое зависит от того , в каком порядке вы определяете оси координат (направление СК - правосторонняя или левосторонняя), и в каком порядке определено вращение. Порядок поворотов по углам Эйлера четко определен. Поэтому ваш алгоритм может варьироваться, и видимо поэтому у них реализовано какое-то переключение.

Для разных объектов предпочтительно вращение в разном порядке. Например при управлении человеком, машиной на  поверхности - сначала происходит вращение вокруг вертикали (рыскание), потом крен и тангаж (может варьироваться порядок), при управлении самолетом или другим объектом  в трех измерениях - крен,  тангаж, рыскание (соответствует порядку углов Эйлера).

Приведу комментарии из проекта , над которым я работал (написаны мною)

```
// Потядок вращений для углов Эйлера:
//
// вращает ССК вокруг изначальной x на 'roll' (крен)
// вращает ССК вокруг изначальной y на 'pitch' (тангаж)
// вращает ССК вокруг изначальной z на 'yaw' (рыскание).
//               .
//              /|\ yaw axis
//               |     __.
//  ._        ___|      /| pitch axis
// _||\       \\ |-.   /
// \|| \_______\_|__\_/_______
//  | _ _   o o o_o_o_o o   /_\__  ________\ roll axis
//  //  /_______/    /__________/          /   
// /_,-'       //   /
//            /__,-'
//
```

Это иллюстрирует порядок осей. Если одна ось переворачивается, система становится "зеркальной", что соответствует перестановке столбцов матриц преобразования и  т.п.